# Is it possible to wait on the main thread for the main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to use a WebView as a Javascript-Interpreter. To check if some libraries are already loaded, I wanted to use a CountDownLatch which gets counted down in the onPageFinished()-method of the WebViewClient. It looks like this:

```
public JsInterpreter(Context context) {
    interpreterWebView = new WebView(context);
    interpreterWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    interpreterWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewReadyListener());

    webViewReadyCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    interpreterWebView.loadUrl(/*javascriptLibrary*/);
}

public void javaScriptRequest(String request) {
    webViewReadyCountDownLatch.await();
    interpreterWebView.loadUrl( "javascript:" + request );
}

private class WebViewReadyListener extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
        webViewReadyCountDownLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

First I thought this would be a good idea because like this I can wait for the library to be loaded but I haven't to deal with listeners when I call my javaScriptRequest()-method. But I forgot that both, the javaScriptRequest()- and the onPageFinished()-method, run on the main thread (in my case), so when I call await() the thread stops running and onPageFinished() never gets called => deadlock.

But is there any working approach to wait (on the main thread) for the page being loaded?

Comment: Why not call `javaScriptRequest()` on a background thread?

Comment: Let's imagine that I want to present this method to someone else and I tell him "please only call this method from a background thread". First this would be ugly and second how can I ensure that the method is really called from a background thread?

Comment: You can fork your own thread, rather than relying on the caller to do so.

Comment: But if the javascript-request should compute a result, post it via a JavascriptInterface to the JsInterpreter class and the javaScriptRequest()-method should return this result? It ends in the same problem ...

Comment: Rewrite your API to be properly asynchronous. `javaScriptRequest()` should not be returning anything, but instead should accept some sort of listener object that can be called when the result is ready.

Comment: Okay, so we get to the conclusion that it's not possible to wait for an event happening on the main thread but that my problem can be solved with a different approach. I suspected that this would be the result of this topic. Thanks for your hints anyway.